# Jekyll pointing to the wrong version of ruby

Tags: ruby, web, rubygems, jekyll

I am fairly new to using Ruby, Rubygems, jekyll, bundler, and the like. It's not my area of knowledge. But I know enough regarding how to use the terminal to get around this lack of knowledge.

I have Ruby 3.0.0 installed, but for some reason, I get the following in terminal when I run jekyll.

I run:

```
jekyll new blog
```

and get the following:

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:281:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem jekyll (>= 0.a) with executable jekyll (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:300:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
```

These are my local gems:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

abbrev (default: 0.1.0)
base64 (default: 0.1.0)
benchmark (default: 0.1.1)
bigdecimal (default: 3.0.0)
bundler (default: 2.4.6)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
cgi (default: 0.2.0)
concurrent-ruby (1.2.0)
csv (default: 3.1.9)
date (default: 3.1.0)
dbm (default: 1.1.0)
debug (default: 0.1.0)
delegate (default: 0.2.0)
did_you_mean (default: 1.5.0)
digest (default: 3.0.0)
drb (default: 2.0.4)
english (default: 0.7.1)
erb (default: 2.2.0)
etc (default: 1.2.0)
executable-hooks (1.6.1)
fcntl (default: 1.0.0)
ffi (1.15.5)
fiddle (default: 1.0.6)
fileutils (default: 1.5.0)
find (default: 0.1.0)
forwardable (default: 1.3.2)
forwardable-extended (2.6.0)
gem-wrappers (1.4.0)
getoptlong (default: 0.1.1)
http_parser.rb (0.8.0)
i18n (1.12.0)
io-console (default: 0.5.6)
io-nonblock (default: 0.1.0)
io-wait (default: 0.1.0)
ipaddr (default: 1.2.2)
irb (default: 1.3.0)
jekyll-sass-converter (2.2.0)
jekyll-watch (2.2.1)
json (default: 2.5.1)
kramdown (2.4.0)
kramdown-parser-gfm (1.1.0)
liquid (4.0.4)
listen (3.8.0)
logger (default: 1.4.3)
matrix (default: 0.3.1)
mercenary (0.4.0)
minitest (5.14.2)
mutex_m (default: 0.1.1)
net-ftp (default: 0.1.1)
net-http (default: 0.1.1)
net-imap (default: 0.1.1)
net-pop (default: 0.1.1)
net-protocol (default: 0.1.0)
net-smtp (default: 0.2.1)
nkf (default: 0.1.0)
observer (default: 0.1.1)
open-uri (default: 0.1.0)
open3 (default: 0.1.1)
openssl (default: 2.2.0)
optparse (default: 0.1.0)
ostruct (default: 0.3.1)
pathname (default: 0.1.0)
pathutil (0.16.2)
power_assert (1.2.0)
pp (default: 0.1.0)
prettyprint (default: 0.1.0)
prime (default: 0.1.2)
pstore (default: 0.1.1)
psych (default: 3.3.0)
racc (default: 1.5.1)
rake (13.0.3)
rb-fsevent (0.11.2)
rb-inotify (0.10.1)
rbs (1.0.0)
rdoc (default: 6.3.0)
readline (default: 0.0.2)
readline-ext (default: 0.1.1)
reline (default: 0.2.0)
resolv (default: 0.2.0)
resolv-replace (default: 0.1.0)
rexml (3.2.4)
rinda (default: 0.1.0)
rouge (3.30.0)
rss (0.2.9)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.5)
rubygems-update (3.4.6)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
safe_yaml (1.0.5)
sassc (2.4.0)
securerandom (default: 0.1.0)
set (default: 1.0.1)
shellwords (default: 0.1.0)
singleton (default: 0.1.1)
stringio (default: 3.0.0)
strscan (default: 3.0.0)
syslog (default: 0.1.0)
tempfile (default: 0.1.1)
terminal-table (2.0.0)
test-unit (3.3.7)
time (default: 0.1.0)
timeout (default: 0.1.1)
tmpdir (default: 0.1.1)
tracer (default: 0.1.1)
tsort (default: 0.1.0)
typeprof (0.11.0)
un (default: 0.1.0)
unicode-display_width (1.8.0)
uri (default: 0.10.1)
weakref (default: 0.1.1)
webrick (1.8.1)
yaml (default: 0.1.1)
zlib (default: 1.1.0)
```

I'm trying to create a static website for my portfolio.

Thanks!

Comment: You are using system Ruby. You don't explain how you installed Ruby 3 but it would appear you did not install it successfully. I would encourage you to read https://dontusesystemruby.com for a full explanation of this issue.

Comment: I was able to handle everything, @anothermh. Thanks for commenting though! What I ended up doing was downloading the most recent version of Ruby (3.2.1) and using that as the global version of my mac (which was 2.6.10). I had to change some things using bash to do that. I also installed the latest version of RubyGems, too. Then, I was able to download Jekyll and Bundle; no issue. To be honest, not sure why I was having so many issues, but all in all, this took a lot of effort.